# error "[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined index: ELEMENT" when running codeception with WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I am trying to get codeceptions acceptance tests running with WebDriver. My current setup is the following:

- Arch Linux
- Chromium: Chromium 75.0.3770.80 Arch Linux
- The included chromedriver-version: ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.80 (9a9aa15057b6b2cc0909bdcf638c0b65ecd516f2-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#948})
- Selenium Server: Selenium server version: 3.14.0, revision: aacccce0

I am executing selenium by running 
`env webdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver" java -jar /usr/share/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone.jar -port 5555 &`
When I run the acceptance tests however, I get the error `[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined index: ELEMENT` for every test. Chromium starts correctly, loads the currect url but is unable to do anything else.

I researched the problem and found out, that there was a similar issue with geckodriver in the past. It could be fixed by passing `-enablePassThrough false` to selenium. The passthrough-mode was removed in selenium 3.9 however. The fix [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/468) was to simply switch to chromedriver. As I am already using chromedriver however, this doesn't work for me. Is it possible, that chromium doesn't support the w3c-specs? Is there any difference between Chromium and Chrome regarding support of Selenium?

The output of selenium: 
starting selenium:

```
11:39:58.474 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revi
11:39:58.478 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 5555
2019-06-07 11:39:58.689:INFO::main: Logging initialized @558ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
11:39:58.895 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 5555
```

starting codeception-tests

```
11:40:24.577 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
      "--disable-gpu"
    ]
  }
}
11:40:24.580 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.80 (9a9aa15057b6b2cc0909bdcf638c0b65ecd516f2-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#948})
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
11:40:26.065 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: W3C
11:40:26.130 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 0c80ffc4e6c160d2817ab60ced6a279f (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

The acceptance tests should be fine as they run fine in my CI-Pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php-webdriver library does not support `w3c` mode yet.
You could pass `w3c: false` as a required capability to get legacy behaviour,
but a more reliable option is to use ChromeDriver v74.

More information can be found in this ticket https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/469#issuecomment-499519728

**Update:** upgrading `facebook/webdriver` library to 1.7.0 version should fix this issue too.

Comment: Downgrading to v74 fixed it for me, thanks! Could you probably include an example-configuration for codeception on using the w3c-option? I wasn't able to get that running. That might help people without the option to downgrade.